# Is there a method to cut a hypercube into disjoint cubes

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, discrete-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

Since Borsuk conjecture hold for centrally symmetric convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$
so we can cut a hypercube into at least $n+1$ disjoint parts.

Is there a method how can one do that?

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: If $[-1,1]^n$ is decomposed into $[-1,0]\times[-1,1]^{n-1}$ and $(0,1]\times [-1,1]^{n-1}$, then the two pieces have diameter $2\sqrt{n-\frac 34}$ while the hypercube has diameter $2\sqrt n$, showing that the hypercube is not a counterexample.

Comment: The Borsuk conjecture on centrally symmetric convex sets only guarantees pieces with smaller diameter, not similar figures.